# excel SUMIFS with 3 criteria in two rows

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm having trouble making SUMIFS to work for my sheets.

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 is a payment plan detail for accounts:

1. Row A is the ID of accounts.
2. Row D is accounts' payment terms.
3. Row H is what I want to sum depending on the following conditions:
4. 1, Match the account ID in Sheet2

   2, Only sum terms from P to Q in Sheet2.(>=P, <=Q)

**I'm hoping to add this code at the end of each row in Sheet2**

For example,

For Row 2 in Sheet2: account no. 180723540400645 needs to sum term 4-24.

We look at Sheet1, and for all rows in column A that equals "180723540400645", sum column H when column D is between 4 and 24.

My code is `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!A:A,"=Sheet2!C2",Sheet1!D:D,">=P2",Sheet1!D:D,"<=Q2")`But it keeps getting 0.
Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Thanks!

EDITS: I tried to just get the sum of all matching account ID in Sheet1, according to a comment. But it's still zero somehow... `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!A:A,"=Sheet2!C3")`

Comment: Why have you put double quotes around Sheet2!C2 ?

Comment: I used excel's formula builder, and this is what it did. I tested without, still 0

Comment: Well, just do the first part up to using the C2 criteria and get that to work, then add the rest.

Comment: Like, try do get the sum that match account ID(C)?

Comment: hmm good suggestion, but somehow it's still 0..

Comment: i wonder if the syntax for equal is not simply "=bluh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula should read:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!C2,Sheet1!D:D,">="&P2,Sheet1!D:D,"<="&Q2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rory! This works like a charm! I guess my mistakes were _the criteria relation should be in quote_? Another quick question, what does `&` do before `P2` and `Q2`? Thanks again!

Comment: @shaoooo you need the `&` to concatenate the **values** of P2 and Q2 into the criteria strings, otherwise your criteria are literally the text values "P2" and "Q2"